# jQuery hide, show when realtimechat code not working

Tags: jquery, socket.io

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRfku.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQw6E.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AfZLq.png)
I got problem that after input username, the #login did not hide and the #Content not show,
could someone help me with this problems

I try to fix the socket.emit and socket.on but everything is ok, the problem just is the jQuery hide,show

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.